# How to get data from excel spreadsheet into text document

Tags: javascript, office365, converters

There is a table that is filled automatically. I need to get the data and format it into an array for javascript (VueJs). But the data contains separator characters in each column: here is an example

```
=================================================
| H|D |  M  |  T  |  S  |  W  |  F  |  S  |  W  |
=================================================
| 0   | 1/2 | 3/1 | 4/4 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1   | 1/2 | 3/1 | 4/4 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 2   | 1/2 | 3/1 | 4/4 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 3   | 1/2 | 3/1 | 4/4 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 4   | 1/2 | 3/1 | 4/4 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 5   | 1/2 | 3/1 | 4/4 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 6   | 1/2 | 3/1 | 4/4 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 | 5/7 |
-------------------------------------------------
|24h                   and                 7 day|
-------------------------------------------------
```

How to get this from this:

```
//M-T1 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//T-T1 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//S-T1 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//W-T1 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//F-T1 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//S-T1 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//W-T1 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']

//M-T2 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//T-T2 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//S-T2 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//W-T2 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//F-T2 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//S-T2 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
//W-T2 ['1', '1', '3', '6', '9', '7', '3']
```

> ***T1*** is the number before the separator
> ***T2*** is the number after the separator

Comment: export as csv and read the csv could be easier

Comment: @Alex, if i start getting data in this way, then it is formatted in two columns.

Comment: okay well can you explain the data inside your table. I don't get how you get from the first to the second table.

Comment: @Alex, Inside the table, these are amounts for work per hour. Every day and every hour has its own cost of work